# Getting the Value from Getter and Setters in Java

Tags: java, setter, getter

This are the getters and setters:

```
public class Icb_Model {

private double price;
private double totalPrice;
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;

}
public double getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}
public void setTotalPrice(double totalPrice) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;

    }

}
```

Class that has method that sets price according to the code read on the txtfile and sets the totalPrice:

```
public class Icb_Cart {

    public void addToCart() throws IOException {

            Scanner prodRead = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Isaiah\\Desktop\\TRUE FINAL PROJ\\FinalProjectPCode.txt"));
            String data = null;
            while(prodRead.hasNextLine()) 
            data = prodRead.nextLine();

            Icb_Model model = new Icb_Model();
        switch(data) {
        case "nb1":
                model.setPrice(29995);
                break;

        case "nb2":
            model.setPrice(24995);
                break;

            }
            model.setTotalPrice(model.getPrice() + model.getTotalPrice());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, model.getTotalPrice());
}
```

Class that calls the method:

```
JButton btnAddCart = new JButton("Add to Cart");
        btnAddCart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String code = "nb1";
                try {
                    FileWriter nbcode = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Isaiah\\Desktop\\TRUE FINAL PROJ\\FinalProjectPCode.txt");
                    nbcode.write(code);
                    nbcode.flush();
                    nbcode.close();


                    cartMethod.addToCart();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnAddCart.setBounds(696, 11, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnAddCart);
```

The output is always 29995 but doesn't add up. How do i retain the values and add up the price to the totalPrice as the button Add to Cart is pressed?
Thank you. T_T

Comment: Your `model` should be defined outside of the `while` loop to keep track of data between loop iterations.

Comment: @luk2302  Outside the `while` is not enough. The variable has to be a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new `Icb_Model`  at each add action as this is defined as a local variable in the `addToCart()` method :

```
public void addToCart() throws IOException {                 
 ...
    Icb_Model model = new Icb_Model();
 ...
    model.setPrice(29995);
 ...
}
```

So you can never sum the new value to the previous one.

Make this an instance field and instantiate it once :

```
public class Icb_Cart {
    private  Icb_Model model = new Icb_Model();

    public void addToCart() throws IOException {                 
        ...
        switch(data) {
        case "nb1":
                model.setPrice(29995);
                break;

        case "nb2":
            model.setPrice(24995);
                break;

            }
        model.setTotalPrice(model.getPrice() + model.getTotalPrice());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, model.getTotalPrice());
        ...
}
```

Comment: It's not better to initialize `model` in a constructor ?

Comment: For this case a field initializer appears straighter.

Comment: @davidxxx that makes sense! man thank you so much that worked. i'm really new to java and programming. I'm still having a hard time.

Comment: @Isaiah Louise Tojos Lastra You are welcome. Yes probably but as all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setPrice() on the same object twice, thus replacing the old value stored in the price variable, every time you call setPrice(price) on the same object. This is why you are getting the same output.

You never call setTotalPrice(), thus, never setting the value of the variable totalPrice, so it will always be 0.

With what you are trying to do, your implementation is wrong.

You can do many things to fix this, two ways would be to:

A) Have a list that stores prices, then, in getTotalPrice(), sum up all the values in that list and return the summed value.

B) Instead of setPrice(), implement a method to increment the price, which will add an integer parameter to the totalPrice variable, each time the method is called

Answer (score 0):

Check your while loop. You don't use a block of curly braces so only the next line will be the while body. This will result in data beeing set to the last line and the switch statement beeing executed only once.